# TextField horizontal-scrolling

Tags: blackberry, horizontal-scrolling, labelfield

Hi i have implemented scrolling text horizontally through this link [LabelField Marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613062/how-can-i-display-scroll-text-like-marque-in-blackberry-using-j2me). But i have one problem,the text is scrolling quite good but its been over-written on the original text which was added.Can anyone have any idea how to cope from this problem? I also tried to refresh the view by `invalidate()` but of no use. i have added the screenshot of the problem which i am facing.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to change paint method to next:

```
 public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    currentText = this.getText();
    if (currentChar < currentText.length()) {
        currentText = currentText.substring(currentChar);

    }
    graphics.drawText(currentText, 0, 0, DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS, 200);
}
```

So don't call `super.paint()` in your `paint`.

Comment: thankx @Eugen.Thankx a lot man :)..its my mistake i called super.paint() in my paint method.

Comment: it work nice but it display test from middle to left,  i want to do like, text should moving from right to left even text is Small or large. how i can do with this code can you help me please?

Comment: Take a look in source code - set different font to label field and instead of starting from 0 position and move 4 symbols right on every tick, do start with text.length() and move 4 symbols left (change + operation to minus). If you still have questions - please create new topic

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten (in a more simple way) the answer you linked. It works fine.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    public MyScreen() {

        super();

        MarqueeLabel testLabel2 = new MarqueeLabel("This is a long long " +
                "long long long long long long long long long long long " +
                "long long marquee", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        add(testLabel2);

    }

    class MarqueeLabel extends LabelField {

        // Here MarqueeLabel code from your SO linked example

    }

}
```

Comment: i tried again this morning the way you said but the result is the same..its moving continuously but also over lapping the text...please get me rid out of this.

Comment: I'm using JRE 5.0.0 on 8520 simulator. Java Plugin for Eclipse 1.3.0. Check your configuration.

Comment: rosco..its working fine in simulator but not working in device bold 9700 having os version 6.0